# Compile java with C#

Tags: c#, java, compilation

I would like to compile a Java program through C#. Does anyone know why I cannot take the output of the program, while I can take the errors? How can I print the results from .java?

```
Process p = new Process(); p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_04\\bin\\javac";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "c:\\java\\upgrade.java";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();

p.WaitForExit();           

resultcode.Text = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The output of the program"? Do you mean the output of the compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean "how do I capture both stdout and stderr text from javac.exe?"

You've already got most of the answer:

1) Specify "redirection" in your Process object:

```
Process p = new Process(); 
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javac";
...
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

2) Allocate C# I/O objects to redirect to:

```
StreamReader outputReader = null;
StreamReader errorReader = null;
...
outputReader = p.StandardOutput;
errorReader = p.StandardError;
```

3) Finally, read from your I/O objects:

```
string myText = "StdOut:" + Environment.NewLine;
myText += outputReader.ReadToEnd();

myText += Environment.NewLine + "Stderr:" + Environment.NewLine;
myText += errorReader.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine("Complete output:" + myText);
```

4) Finally, if you *DON'T*  want to open your own I/O objects, then *DON'T* set `p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;`.